# MutationObserver for class (not for id)

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

It's not the problem to make MutationObserver work for `#someID`, but what's the way to make it work for `.someClass`?

Currently I'm using the following:

```
// this example doensn't work,
// as well as many another attempts

var target = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var foo = target[i].getAttribute("someAttribute")

            if (foo == "someValue")
                foo.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        });
    });

    // configuration of the observer
    var config = { attributes: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had a few issues:

- iterator: `target[i]` is not what you expect once the code is executed (`var foo = target[i].getAttribute("someAttribute")`), since the iteration is finished when this line is ran, `i` has a value of `target.length`, so `target[i]` does not exist
- attributes don't have styles (`foo.style.backgroundColor`), you need to refer the target element
- you're passing the whole collection to the observer (`observer.observe(target, config);`) you need only one target element

---

Here's the working code after fixing the errors listed above and externalizing the loop code into a function for easier target referencing:

```js
var target = document.querySelectorAll(".c");
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
  create(target[i]);
}

function create(t) {
  // create an observer instance
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      var foo = t.getAttribute("aaa")

      if (foo == "vvv")
        t.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
  });
  // configuration of the observer
  var config = {
    attributes: true
  };

  // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
  observer.observe(t, config);
}

// let's change an attribute in a second
setTimeout(function(){
  target[2].setAttribute('aaa', 'vvv');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.c {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

---

### UPDATE

Here's an example with minimal edits:

- `var foo = target[i].getAttribute("someAttribute")` changed to `var foo = mutation.target.getAttribute("someAttribute")` instead of a passed-in target element

```js
var target = document.querySelectorAll(".someClass");
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var foo = mutation.target.getAttribute("someAttribute")

            if (foo == "someValue")
                mutation.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        });
    });

    // configuration of the observer
    var config = { attributes: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target[i], config);
}

// let's change an attribute in a second
setTimeout(function(){
  target[2].setAttribute('someAttribute', 'someValue');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.someClass {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="someClass"></div>
```

Comment: Shomz, may be you can take a look to another my question (100 rep bounty), linked to this one? I'm trying to find a way to disconnect and reconnect an observer from your code examples. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290789/reconnect-and-disconnect-a-mutationobserver

Comment: Hi John, are you sure that's the question? Because that one has an answer from 2 days ago and no bounty.

Comment: Hi! The link is correct, I verified. The David's answer *may be* right, but I don't understand it and I decided to ask you, to get more authoritative answer. The bounty is open - [here is the screenshot](http://imgur.com/OkZmDrf). May be it was some bug - StackOverflow worked strange this evening. Try to see now or may be tomorrow. If bounty will be still no visible - then, please, let me know! I will ask on meta or may be write a message to support team.

Comment: Ah, it's there now, I could've sworn it wasn't there when I looked. Anyway, I didn't know you didn't understand or like David's answer - he made the right references to the MDN docs, but maybe an example more similar to your code would've been better. I'll take another look and see if I can come up with something better tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, and btw. see if you can remove the bounty, because the issue was about a bad variable scope, and besides you shouldn't waste your rep until you get some more. :)

Comment: The bounty cannot be removed, it's by design :-) I marked the question as answered, but may be you can also show the example based on your **first** approach? Quote: **"Here's the working code after fixing the errors listed above and externalizing the loop code into a function for easier target referencing".** May be a jsfiddle? It would be very fine :-)

Comment: Sure thing! Although they are very similar, you'll see. I'll update the other answer.