# Infinite Loop in MutationObserver with sort function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

MutationObserver detects when there is a change in the notifyDiv div. After that another function makes the correct order. But this eventually causes a new change in div and enters an Infinite Loop.

```
var target = document.querySelector('.notifyDiv');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var divList = $(".notifyItem");
    divList.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(b).data("id")-$(a).data("id")
    });
    $(".notifyDiv").html(divList);
});
```

Comment: There's not much you can do about that. Is there a reason you're using a MutationObserver in the first place? They should really be used as a last resort. If you have control of when the `.notifyItem` elements are added, raise an event and then handle it

Comment: Call `$(".notifyDiv").html(divList)` only if the order is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reconnect and disconnect a MutationObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290789/reconnect-and-disconnect-a-mutationobserver)

Comment: Hi Fernando essentially you need to disconnect and reconnect your mutation observer. Please check out the information on the q/a I've marked as a possible duplicate (reconnect and disconnect a mutationobserver). If this answers your question, please mark your question so

Comment: @Ror It is a notification center that receives notifications by ajax. Do you know any other method to identify change? I used domsubtreemodified which worked well. But it has been discontinued.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, if you control when the elements are added trigger an event manually on the container you append to. Don't use MutationObservers or DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question if you can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well... for ease, I hid the notifyDiv div and created another identical one called notifyDivShow, so when reordering notifyDiv displays the result only in notifyDivShow.

```
var target = document.querySelector('.notifyDiv');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    var divList = $(".notifyItem");
    divList.sort(function(a, b){
        return $(b).data("id")-$(a).data("id")
    });
    $(".notifyDivShow").html(divList);
});
```

The divs

```
<div class="notifyDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="notifyDivShow"></div>
```