# In Ionic 7, how do I set cursor focus on an IonInput field?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, autofocus, ionic7

I'm using Ionic 7 and React 18.  How do I cause a particular input on a form to automatically have the focus of the cursor when that component is loaded?  I thought "autofocus" was the way

```
          <IonInput
          autofocus
            placeholder='First Name'
            value=''
          />
```

but that is not getting the cursor focus.  An example can be seen here -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-xqjw5k?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx .

**Edit:** Per the answer given, I tried this but the focus does not set to the only field on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and use React's [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) and [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) hooks:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { IonButton, IonInput } from '@ionic/react'

const MyForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLIonInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => { // Added a timeout to make sure the element is loaded
      inputRef.current?.setFocus();
    }, 0);
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <IonInput
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder='First Name'
        value=''
      />
    
      <IonButton type='submit'>Save And Continue</IonButton>
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

The `useRef` hook creates a reference (`inputRef`) to the `IonInput` element.
The `useEffect` hook makes sure the focus is set on the `IonInput` when the component mounts. A timeout is used to make sure the DOM element is loaded before trying to set focus.
The `IonInput` is updated to use `ref={inputRef}` instead of the `autofocus` attribute.

That does set the focus on the `IonInput` field for 'First Name' when `MyForm` component is rendered.

You can see it in action in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-uuzctq?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx).

---

> Is it possible that the setTimeout would be called and the element is not loaded? I was curious if there was a more foolproof way of only applying the focus once we're confident the input is on screen.

Yes, I have update the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-uuzctq?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx).

Since the rendering of the `IonInput` is straightforward and not heavily dependent on asynchronous operations, the simplest and most effective approach should be to make sure the focus is set after the component and all its children are fully mounted.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { IonButton, IonInput } from '@ionic/react'

const MyForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLIonInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
          inputRef.current.setFocus();
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      });

      observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <IonInput
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder='First Name'
        value=''
      />
    
      <IonButton type='submit'>Save And Continue</IonButton>
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

The [`MutationObserver`](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-mutation-observer/) will watch for changes in the DOM. When it detects changes, it checks if the `IonInput` is available and sets the focus.
The disconnecting observer ([mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312379/6309)) allows, once the focus is set, for the observer to be disconnected to prevent further unnecessary checks.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is it possible that the setTimeout would be called and the element is not loaded?  I was curious if there was a more foolproof way of only applying the focus once we're confident the input is on screen.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I have updated the example to illustrate that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method Ionic provides for IonInput component called: [setFocus](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#setfocus)

The example provided will not work b/c you're using a submit type button, using a regular IonButton works.

```
const MyForm = () => {
  const firstNameInput = useRef<HTMLIonInputElement>(null);
  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    firstNameInput.current?.setFocus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <IonInput ref={firstNameInput} placeholder="First Name" value="" />
        <IonButton onClick={handleButtonClick}>Focus Input</IonButton>
        {/* <IonButton type="submit">Save And Continue</IonButton> */}
      </form>
    </>
 );
};
```

Comment: You may want to provide an example b/c I gave that a whirl, https://stackblitz.com/edit/an5yjh-etnmfy?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2FMyForm.tsx, but it doesn't set the focus.

Comment: I may not be understanding you, but I don't want the focus to occur because I click a button, I want the focus to occur when the component is rendered.  As soon as someone navigates to the page, they should be able to type in the input that gets the automatic focus, without their having to click on the input with their mouse (or finger).

Comment: -_- .... Then you should've stated that instead of using a button. I'm just proving that it does work.

Comment: To be fair, I did start my question with "How do I cause a particular input on a form to automatically have the focus of the cursor when that component is loaded"