# How in "observer" to track the change of certain objects?

Tags: javascript

This is the relevant markup:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="adv">...</div>
  <div class="coup">...</div>
  <div class="news">...</div>
  <div class="coup">...</div>
  <div class="adv">...</div>
  <div class="coup">...</div>
</div>
```

The content of all blocks is changing. Tell me, how to follow only blocks with coup class? I found an article on the Internet https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver and there is a callback, but I still do not understand how to fill it:

```
***
switch(mutation.type) {
      case 'childList':
        /* One or more children have been added to and/or removed
           from the tree; see mutation.addedNodes and
           mutation.removedNodes */
        break;
***
```

I assumed I had to place after the `case "childList":` the classes I needed. I tried to do this: `case 'childList': [".coup"]` but it didn't work. Or am I wrong and this is not the article? Can you tell me how to follow only certain elements?

all code

```js
function callback(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach((mutation) => {
    switch(mutation.type) {
      case 'childList':
        break;
      case 'attributes':
        break;
    }
  });
}


var targetNode = document.querySelector(".wrap");
var observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true 
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

Comment: _"...how to follow only certain elements?"_ - What does _"to follow"_ mean? What do you want to do with the `.coup` elements?

Comment: What are you using as the target node for observation?

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097520/mutationobserver-for-class-not-for-id

Comment: @Andreas Excuse me for my English. I was just using an translator. I only need to observe certain classes inside the .wrap block.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I use the code from the example on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver . I have "observer" running, it displays changes in all classes. I just want it to keep track of only some classes. I can't hang "observer" on the objects I need, because the number of these elements is constantly changing.

Comment: @tomerraitz thank you for the link, but this decision doesn't really suit me. I need to monitor the entire .wrap block because the number of .coup blocks is constantly changing.

Comment: I just asked what node you're using as the target. Is it the `div class="wrap"`? It would be  nice to create a [mre] so that people could see a simplified example of what's going on. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to make that happen.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, wrap.

Comment: I suggest debugging the callback function. Put a breakpoint in the case for `childList` and examine what the properties of `mutation` are. If I'm not mistaken, it should have a list of added nodes; you could filter them by class name (`addedNodes.filter(node => node.classList.contains('coup'))`)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the solution, but I don't fully understand how I can use it. I am a novice programmer, so I had some troubles. Could you give me a full example?