# MutationObserver.observe: Argument 1 is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I wanna display a console message when a value of a span attribute (`data-value`) is changed. The span got no ID so I iterate each class out of it. But when I tried to run, it always displayed an error. Here is the HTML:

`<span class="wpsl-selected-item" data-value="50"></span>`

and here is the JS:

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.wpsl-selected-item');
for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
    create(target[i]);
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log('heya')
    });
});

  
var config = {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['data-value']
};

observer.observe(target[i], config);
```

The error message is: `Uncaught TypeError: MutationObserver.observe: Argument 1 is not an object.` and I'm working on firefox

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `.observe(target[i], config)` - The only `i` that is available is the one in `for (var i = ...)`. Expecting it to also correctly work outside of that loop is not a good idea - as you can see here.

Comment: It's not clear what function "create()" is doing, however the variable "i" doesn't mean anything outside your for loop. So "target[i]" it's not what u expect.  Try to start with that :)

Comment: @Plastic _"however the variable "i" doesn't mean anything outside your for loop"_ - That's not correct. It's still available (hoisting, scope) and has a value. But that value, when used as index, will be out-of-bounds of `target`. And `undefined` is not an object...

Comment: @Andreas, u are right, I was pointing that "i" value will be different from what he expect

Comment: @Plastic @Andreas I thought "create()" could make an object for each iterated ```target```

Comment: I'm referring example from this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097520/mutationobserver-for-class-not-for-id). The error is now gone but the message still not displayed on console I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.wpsl-selected-item');
if (target.length > 0) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            console.log('heya')
        });
    });
  
    var config = {
        attributes: true,
        attributeFilter: ['data-value']
    };

    for(var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
        observer.observe(target[i], config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `create()` call?

Comment: @andys It didn't worked, I'm not sure why, does the iteration of a class is an object?

Comment: @rickyslash I am trying it in jsfiddle and it works. [https://jsfiddle.net/nawvye53](https://jsfiddle.net/nawvye53)